# Compound synonyms in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to extract synonyms from a sentence. When synonyms are just words it works well. The problem occurs when synonyms are compound words.

For example, I have registered the following synonyms:
car, big car, vehicle

If I run Analyze in the following sentence:
"The car was moving fast" I get the correct synonyms.

If I search only for "big car" I also get the correct set of synonyms.

However, if I search for "The big car moved fast", I don't get the synonyms for "big car".

I'm using the following configuration:

```json
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym": {
          "type": "synonym_graph",
          "synonyms": [
            "car, big car, vehicle"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "keywords_token": {
          "filter": [
            "my_synonym",
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This solution is not ideal.
What I need is to get the synonym words composed to return to the interface.
The solution that returns only tokens also does not answer, as it does not return synonym tokens in order.

Comment: Are you sure you're giving the real details here? The analyzer you're providing uses a` keyword` tokenizer, which basically doesn't split text. That can't be right. Also, your synonym_graph token filter is declared incorrectly. Synonyms have to be comma-separated and within a single string.

Comment: Hello Evaldas. I edited part of the creation of my index to summarize it and generate the example. I'm using the 'keyword' tokenizer to get the return of compound synonyms. I am looking for a solution to find synonyms composed within a long sentence.